# Joomla 3.4 login api - how to "remember" session

Tags: joomla-api, joomla-3.4

This works great for 3.4 Joomla.  How do I keep the user logged in? i.e. "remember"?

```
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('user');
$options = array();
$options['action'] = 'core.login.site';
$response->username = "user_name_here";
$result = $app->triggerEvent('onUserLogin', array((array)$response, $options));
```

$options['remember'] = TRUE doesn't seem to work.  Does anyone know if this particular API call supports a remember me option.  Users stay logged in but are immediately logged out when the browser window is closed.

UPDATE:

i was able to get remember me working by following tips at this site to fix session.cookie lifetime on the server settings: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=470&t=457307&start=30

added following to index.php in joomla - hopefully helps others out.

`ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 536*60*60);`

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer and accept it!

Comment: You've found your workaround, however note that API should be stateless, and should not involve sessions.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me last time I did that.

```
<?php
// login the new user
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$options = array(
    'remember' => true,
    'return' => '',
);
$credentials = array(
    'username' => $user['username'],
    'password' => $user['password_clear'],
);
if ($app->login($credentials, $options)!==true) $this->close(false,'Could not login new user account.');
```